# How to root my new Galaxy SII

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s-2, rom

I just bought my Galaxy SII. Can anyone here tell me how to root my phone with Lite'Ning?

Baseband:I9100GDZKH5
Kernel: 2.6.35.7 root@DELL81 #2
Build: GINGERBREAD.JPKH8

Answer (score 1):

You can find a detailed guide with screenshots and all [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1095274). It's done with odin.

> Step 1: Install Odin v1.85 on your computer then download and unrar
>   the Lite'ning Rom rar file.
>
> Step 2: Make sure that your phone is in USB debugging mode: Settings
>   -> Applications -> Development -> USB debugging.
>
> Step 3: Reboot your phone into download mode. To do so: Turn the
>   device off, then power it on again by pressing and holding the Volume
>   Down + Home + Power on simultaneously.
>
> Step 4: Start Odin.
>
> Step 5: Connect the phone to your computer using the USB cable.
>
> Step 6: Wait a few seconds, the Odin screen will show that a device is
>   now connected... Added!!
>
> - Make sure that in Odin nothing is checked, except the "Auto reboot" and "F. Reset Time" checkboxes.
> - Press the "PDA" button, and select the md5 file.
> - Press "Start". Odin will now flash the Lite'ning Rom, after flashing your phone should reboot.
>
> Step 7: Done! Now you have a fully rooted SGS II with the Lite'ning
>   Rom installed!